A corollary of the invariance domain theorem?
For $n\geq 1$, let $f\in\mathcal{C}\big(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n\big)$ an injective continuous function. Let $\mathcal{O}$ a nonempty open and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Do the following hold ("$\partial$" meaning "border of"):
$$\partial\Big[f(\mathcal{O})\Big]=\Big[f(\partial\mathcal{O})\Big]?$$

Note that the closure satisfies $\bar{\mathcal{O}} = \mathcal{O} \sqcup \partial\mathcal{O}$. Since $f$ is injective, it is locally a homeomorphism between $\mathcal{O}$ and $f(\mathcal{O})$. This implies that
\begin{align}
f(\bar{\mathcal{O}}) &= f(\mathcal{O}) \sqcup f(\partial\mathcal{O})\\
\Rightarrow f(\partial\mathcal{O}) &= f(\bar{\mathcal{O}}) \setminus \tag{1} f(\mathcal{O})
\end{align}
Since $\mathcal{O}$ is bounded, we have that $\bar{\mathcal{O}}$ is closed and bounded, and hence compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since the continuous image of a compact set is compact, we have that $f(\bar{\mathcal{O}})$ is compact as well, and hence closed. Since $f$ is continuous, it now follows that
$$ f(\bar{\mathcal{O}}) = \overline{f({\mathcal{O}})} \tag{2}$$
Finally, observe that $\overline{f({\mathcal{O}})} = f({\mathcal{O}}) \sqcup \partial f(\mathcal{O})$, which implies
$$ \partial f(\mathcal{O}) = \overline{f({\mathcal{O}})} \setminus f({\mathcal{O}}) \tag{3} $$
Combining $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$ gives the desired result.
